# Shading selected cell with a certain colour at key press in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a student and I have to learn a lot of stuff/questions, so I came up with an idea and I don't know how to realize it.

So all I am asking is for someone *kind* to show me how I can program Excel to specifically shade the selected cell with a certain color with a press of a button, as the title suggests.

I want to get in a **special mode**, where:

1. I can move around the cells with the arrow keys
2. by pressing 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, then the selected cell gets shaded with a specific color. (each number for a different color)

The question is, how do I do it? Is something like that possible at all in Excel? I have some background with code, but not even close to a professional. I just did VB Stuff for my GCE A Levels in Computing.

Macros are also possible as I can see but really don't know how to use them.

So here I am, asking this question, hoping someone kind will maybe see it as a challenge and help me realize it. I would invest the time to learn how to do this myself, but with the free time I have now, something like that would take months, just because I'm thorough and I want to learn from the absolute basics.

Comment: Isn't that a bit like cheating?  Chances are a plaigrised answer from SO will be detected by examiners are fairly high.  Find the time to learn what you need.  Or choose to FAIL.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I've downvoted for the begging, and I've reported your unfriendly tone to a moderator,  M. Kleanthous. This is not a good start for you here. @Mark is surely in earnest that this feels like cheating, even if you can supply reasons why it is not. At the very least it is a request for free work ("I don't have time to learn this, please do it for me").

Comment: Could Mark have been more friendly? Possibly, but if you understand that your question was skating on thin ice to start with, that will help your understand why you did not get an enthusiastic reception. It is important not to retaliate too. Please [read the Code](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) when you get a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter this ***special*** mode you can run a macro to assign new purposes to those keys.

In a module in the VBE Editor, you can add:

```
Sub EnterSpecialMode()
    Call Application.OnKey("1", "color1")
    Call Application.OnKey("2", "color2")
    Call Application.OnKey("3", "color3")
    Call Application.OnKey("4", "color4")
End Sub

Sub ExitSpecialMode()
    Call Application.OnKey("1")
    Call Application.OnKey("2")
    Call Application.OnKey("3")
    Call Application.OnKey("4")
End Sub

Sub color1()
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub

Sub color2()
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End Sub

Sub color3()
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
End Sub

Sub color4()
    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End Sub
```

Self-explanatory, but to enter the special mode you have to run the *EnterSpecialMode*. And to exit run the *ExitSpecialMode* sub

Comment: So I opened VisualBasic and pasted the code for the whole workbook. I run the enterspecialmode macro , pressed a number and got the following error "Cannot run the macro 'Book1color3'. The macro may not be available in the workbook or all macros may be disabled" I checked my macro security settings and it's all fine. What should I do?

Comment: @M.Kleanthous make sure you created a New Module by right-clicking and "insert new module" then put the code in there.

Comment: Thank you Kubie, this works! And thank you for the fast replies!